# Выполнить действие по нажатию кнопки

Tags: javascript, jquery

По нажатию кнопки есть код который выполняется

```
$("#add-"+key_room_type+"-"+key_room)
                            .button()
                            .click(function ( event ) {

                                if (this.checked){
                                    //alert('true');
.........}
```

как выполнить этот код при изменении другого элемента?

```
$("#select-"+key_room_type+"-"+key_room+"number_ead")
                            .select()
                            .change( function( event){

                            //alert ('КАК тут выполнить код из кнопки!!');


                            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Быстрое решение - можно принудительно вызвать событие click:

```
$("#add-"+key_room_type+"-"+key_room).trigger('click');
```

Примечание: более правильно, но более затратно по времени, - можно было бы вынести код, который выполняется при клике на кнопку, - в отдельную функцию. И вызывать эту функцию 2 раза:

```
function foo(bar){
    // Ваша функция
}

$("#add-"+key_room_type+"-"+key_room)
                        .button()
                        .click(function ( event ) {
                        // Вызов функции
                        foo(bar);

.........}

$("#select-"+key_room_type+"-"+key_room+"number_ead")
                        .select()
                        .change( function( event){

                        //alert ('КАК тут выполнить код из кнопки!!');
                        // Вызов функции
                        foo(bar)

                        });
```

Comment: кхм-кхм, не слишком ли быстрое? Переменные `key_room_type` и `key_room` в обработчике `change` могут быть не теми, что при его навешивании.

Comment: спасибо! Понимаю что правильно в отдельную функцию вывести, но код не мой и там куча циклов в цикле боюсь напортачить, да и не силён я в javascript, а сделать надо срочно, прям вчера уже :-)

Comment: да, да Igor, правильно подметил, это я учёл.

Answer (score 1):

Записывайте параметры для генерации `id` кнопки в `data`-свойства селекта:

```
$("#select-"+key_room_type+"-"+key_room+"number_ead")
  .select()
  .change( function(event) {
    //alert ('КАК тут выполнить код из кнопки!!');
    $("#add-" + $(this).data("keyroomtype") + "-" + $(this).data("keyroom")).click();
  }).
  data("keyroomtype", key_room_type).
  data("keyroom", key_room);
```

Comment: это тоже сделал, спасибо.